# Python import spacy sentence bert

Tags: python, nlp, spacy, bert-language-model

I'm trying to import `import spacy_sentence_bert`and run the following code in python.

I installed `conda install -c conda-forge spacy-transformers` on the anaconda prompt.

```py
import spacy_sentence_bert
nlp = spacy_sentence_bert.load_model('en_stsb_bert_large')
```

The error that I'm receiving is the following:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'spacy_sentence_bert'
```

I had this working, however, I had to uninstall Python recently due to another error and now its not working.

Any help will be appreciated, I'm not so well-versed in Python.

Im using Python 3.9.12 downloaded thru Anaconda with Spyder IDE.

Comment: I suppose this error may be caused by several python executables or by different (obviously not active by default) environment where the module was installed. Check the path to the python you use right now if it's connected with required conda env where the module is located.

Comment: I think that was the case.  I also installed: conda install pytorch torchvision torchaudio cudatoolkit=11.3 -c pytorch and pip install -U sentence-transformers --user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to install [`spacy-sentence-bert`](https://pypi.org/project/spacy-sentence-bert/), either with `pip install spacy-sentence-bert` or the conda equivalent. (Mixing conda and pip often works, but can sometimes result in strange errors.)

`spacy-transformers` is a separate package, and is for wrapping Transformers in spaCy in general. It's kind of confusing, but [`sentence-transformers`](https://pypi.org/project/sentence-transformers/) is also a separate package, and `spacy-sentence-bert` is a wrapper for that package.